cuSPARSELt not found by CuPy
I have a hard time getting CuPy to detect and use, where applicable, the cuSPARSELt library in Windows. I tried installing versions 0.2.0 (as mentioned by CuPy's installation guide) and 0.6.2 (the latest version as of the time of posting), and in both tries, cusparseLt.dll was found successfully using where cusparseLt.dll.
Am I missing something here? Here is the output of cupy.show_config()
OS                           : Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
Python Version               : 3.12.5
CuPy Version                 : 13.3.0
CuPy Platform                : NVIDIA CUDA
NumPy Version                : 2.1.0
SciPy Version                : 1.14.1
Cython Build Version         : 0.29.36
Cython Runtime Version       : None
CUDA Root                    : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.4
nvcc PATH                    : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.4\bin\nvcc.EXE
CUDA Build Version           : 12060
CUDA Driver Version          : 12030
CUDA Runtime Version         : 12060 (linked to CuPy) / 12040 (locally installed)
CUDA Extra Include Dirs      : []
cuBLAS Version               : 120405
cuFFT Version                : 11201
cuRAND Version               : 10305
cuSOLVER Version             : (11, 6, 1)
cuSPARSE Version             : 12301
NVRTC Version                : (12, 4)
Thrust Version               : 200600
CUB Build Version            : 200600
Jitify Build Version         : 1a0ca0e
cuDNN Build Version          : 8801
cuDNN Version                : 8801
NCCL Build Version           : None
NCCL Runtime Version         : None
cuTENSOR Version             : 20001
cuSPARSELt Build Version     : None
Device 0 Name                : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090
Device 0 Compute Capability  : 89
Device 0 PCI Bus ID          : 0000:01:00.0

Here is my current os.environ["PATH"] output, with some formatting:
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet-core-uninstall
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
C:\Program Files\dotnet
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v98\runtime\win64
C:\Program Files\Matrox Imaging\Mil\DLL
C:\Program Files\Matrox Imaging\Tools
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\Program Files\OpenSSH
C:\Users\LILBRO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
C:\Users\LILBRO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts
C:\Users\LILBRO\Documents\Tools\CUDA\cuSPARSELt\current
C:\Users\LILBRO\Documents\Tools\CUDA\cuSPARSELt\current\include
C:\Users\LILBRO\Documents\Tools\CUDA\cuSPARSELt\current\lib


It appears that only specific versions of cusparseLt are supported, and I'm not sure 0.6.2 or 0.2.0 are supported.  See here for what appear to be the requirements, and here for additional background.  Aside: You also seem to have a mismatch between your installed CUDA version and the CUDA version that was used to build cupy, although that may not matter if your GPU driver is new enough.

I can swear the required version was 0.2.0 not even an hour ago... I'll see if the new requirements fixes this, and thanks for pointing out the CUDA version mismatches. I'll upgrade as soon as I can.

I just noticed: The recommended cuSPARSELt version for CuPy's latest release is 0.6.0/0.6.1, but CuPy's stable release still recommends 0.2.0 for cuSPARSELt. From what I can tell, the one I have is the stable release. I'll try and see if the latest/nightly release solves this.

comparing the latest and the stable docs, they both appear to refer to cupy 13.3.0  So I'm not sure what the difference is.  On that webpage, at least, 13.3.0 has a "latest" identifier

Nope, still no luck. No matter the versions, cuSPARSELt fails to show-up as loaded.

based on the install info, and noting that there is a conda-forge package for cusparseLt, perhaps try installing via one of the two methods suggested for other cuda libraries that need manual installation: conda install -c conda-forge cupy cusparselt or python -m cupyx.tools.install_library --cuda 12.x --library cusparselt

Currently (as of CuPy v13), CuPy's binary packages are not built with cuSPARSELt support enabled. You need to rebuild CuPy from source to use cuSPARSELt bindings in CuPy. I'd suggest raising an issue along with your use case if you need cuSPARSELt support in binary packages.

@kmaehashi: that is a perfect answer if you care to add it


I have a hard time getting CuPy to detect and use, where applicable, the cuSPARSELt library

A Cupy developer commented that at present, release builds of Cupy don’t have cuSPARSELt support enabled. To do that, you would require building your own version of the package from source with support enabled.
